# PHP FTP Download NOT COPY

Tags: php, ftp, download

I have try some code to download file using FTP, But File not send in computer client.
this code is just copy file from another folder in server computer.
Could you show me the solution.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
//FTP File Download
$file_name      = 'myfile.xml';
$destination    = '/download/'.$file_name;
$ftp_user_name  = 'chelsea';
$ftp_user_pass  = 'drogba';
$ftp_server = '192.168.1.1';
$conn_id    = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result   = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

ftp_nb_get($conn_id, $destination, $file_name, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Why not ftp_get instead of ftp_nb_get

Comment: With `ftp_nb_*` function, you'll have to keep calling [`ftp_nb_continue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-continue.php) until it reaches `FTP_FINISHED` or `FTP_FAILED`.

Comment: file still not downloaded into client computer.

Answer (score 0):

be sure The Ftp server Allow to Get file Server-to-server if not allow you cant use this function.

and test This code

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = '<save-file-as>';
$server_file = '<server-file-name>';
$server_directory='/';
$ftp_user_name='<ftp-user>';
$ftp_user_pass='<ftp-pass>';
$ftp_server='<ftp-host-name>';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

/* uncomment if you need to change directories*/
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $server_directory)) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}


// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
   echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
   echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: the code is running well, no error. but  just copy file from one folder to another folder in server computer. not send in client computer... if the FTP server must set to get File server-to-server how to set that function.

Comment: in FTP Server Config you Can find setting for This. also you can Test this class [Ftp](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1743-PHP-FTP-client-in-pure-PHP.html) It Must Work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl to download a file from ftp

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("myfile.xml", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com/myfile.xml"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

[PHP: download any file from ftp-server to harddrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278553/php-download-any-file-from-ftp-server-to-harddrive?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: still copy not download to client computer.

Answer (score 0):

After the script downloaded the file from the second server to the one running the script, you can send it to the client with `readfile` and the appropiate headers (see here: [Headers used to download file php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513420/headers-used-to-download-file-php) )

Of course it will get sent via HTTP because the request to the PHP script was a HTTP request and you cannot change the protocol on the fly.

Comment: how to set download directly to user folder for example C:/download/... i need that process because i don't wont user change to save to another folder. because after process download application will read automatically from that folder.

Comment: Not possible. Would you want me to fumble with your hard drive when you visit my website? Or are you talking about a desktop application?

Comment: I have build a combination program about Desktop and Web App.

Comment: So where is the PHP code above running and how does it get called? This is important, you should update the question with details.

Comment: in this question, i need just how to download directly to user folder.

Comment: Only from within your desktop application. That's why I asked.